# Is it possible to make the data in a firebase database anonymous?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a mobile app that stores personal data in a Firebase database. Ideally, when I log in to the Firebase console I don't want to be able to see the data that belongs to a user. However, this is possible because the Firebase Authentication page gives me a list of users with their user ids, and I've structured the database so that a user's data is under a reference using their user id. As far as I know, this is the recommended way to structure the database (the security rules for the database are then fairly simple as a result).

Is it possible to make it so that looking at the list of users on the authentication page doesn't allow me (or anyone else who has access to the console) to figure out who owns what data?

Answer (score 0):

*Firebase employee here*

I don't believe there is any way to alter the data on the Firebase Authentication screen to omit the UIDs for each user.  This sounds like a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) that you could log, and might be something the team could implement in the future with fine-grained IAM permissions.  But I don't anticipate that happening in the very near future.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm also concerned about this because if my Firebase account was compromised by a hacker, they would also be able to connect up the users with their data. I've started down the route of encrypting all of the data but that has the disadvantage of making it completely unreadable, so it won't be possible to do any data processing with it. My preferred solution would be just to make all the data anonymous, perhaps, as you've suggested, by hiding the user ids somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your concern there.  This is all relevant to state in a feature request.  The problem is that this would have to be a permanent change you opt into with the console, as anyone who hacks your account could just change it back, if that option exists.